# D3 map images not showing on mobile devices (iPhone)

Tags: d3.js

I have developed a map with circle images overlaid. It works properly on my desktop browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome) but on an iPhone the map gets drawn but not the images. On the iPad images display with question marks. Clearly mousemove actions will not work on mobile devices but click actions should. On the iPad, the click (i.e. touch) acts like mouseover.
Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any code.

Comment: I can provide code but another mystery may give a clue. When I use Firefox 26.0 I can see the map and images. However, a friend using the same version of Firefox can see the map but none of the images. However, if she mouseovers the area where the images should be the display shows and if she clicks on the area the popup window also appears. So the images are ghosts. I should also add that I have not added any event handlers for mobile actions such as touch. Do you know of any good references for using them with D3?

Comment: Can't post script due to limits on length but I have posted it to http://www.climateactionnow.ca/map-script

Comment: Hmm, could be all sorts of things. Have you had a look at http://henkelmann.eu/2010/12/16/display_svg_image_same_size_in_decent_browsers

Comment: Could anything explain the different behaviours with the same version of Firefox? and the same Mac OS Mavericks?

Comment: Image load times? It sounds like the image may be taking too long to load, i.e. the DOM is rendered and after that the image is loaded, but not rendered.

Comment: Possibly. She has a slower processor. Also less RAM.

Comment: As a temporary workaround I disabled displaying images and instead displayed a coloured circle. Would it be easy (given my limited knowledge) to have the circle display first and the image after?

Comment: No, you can't really influence that. One idea might be to set some attribute on the circles that causes a redraw after a timeout.